# Find what changes took place after apt-get update

Tags: raspbian, update

my problem is my Raspbian (with PREEMPT-RT patch) is freezing after performing sudo apt-get update.

Is there any logs or anyway to know what happened to Raspbian after this update. so that I can figure out what makes conflict with the PREEMPT-RT patch.

p.s: in Raspberry website it is mentioned that downloaded package files (.deb files) are kept in /var/cache/apt/archives. but I believe that there are other changes in the system that caused this freezing.

Comment: *"I believe that there are other changes in the system"* -> I'm almost positive that one way or another this could be deduced from the list of modified packages, although the worst case scenario I have in mind is pretty ugly as it involves scanning the packages themselves.  You might take your awareness of this and ask a more specific question about that on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), since the package management system is not unique to the pi and is used on a very wide variety of (possibly even *most*) GNU/Linux systems.

Comment: As always, make a backup before performing a change you don't know how to undo.

Answer (score 1):

From [apt-get manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources.

It only updates what is available, it does **not** make any changes to your system!

Perhaps you are thinking "upgrade"? The answer to that is available on [UNIX StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46453/174496).